# Generic lambda vs generic function give different behaviour

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Take following code as an example

```
#include <algorithm>

namespace baz {
    template<class T>
    void sort(T&&){}
}

namespace boot {
    const auto sort = [](auto &&){};
}

void foo (){
    using namespace std;
    using namespace baz;
    sort(1);
}

void bar(){
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boot;
    sort(1);
}
```

I expected that since `foo` compiled, then `bar` shall compile as well. To my surprise, the `foo` compiles correctly and `bar` has problem with ambiguous call to `sort` function. Am I doing something illegal here or this is proper way compiler should behave? If so, why is it so different. I though generic lambda can be treated as syntactic sugar for generic function.

[live example](https://godbolt.org/z/8foQwP)

Comment: Lambdas do not participate in ADL

Comment: This isn't ADL. An `int` argument doesn't come from any namespace.

Comment: Should this really be ambiguous, though?  `std::sort()` doesn't take 1 parameter as input, it takes at least 2, so why is the compiler even considering it as a candidate for a call that passes only 1 parameter value?

Comment: There must be something about the extra layer of indirection that the lambda introduces. With the first example, the call is made to `::baz::sort`, but in the second example, it would have to find `::boot::mystery_lambda_type::operator()`. That extra step might be what causes `std::sort` to be considered first. I don't have the standard in front of me so can't be sure about this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is not that the call to `sort` is ambiguous, but that the name `sort` is ambiguous. Name lookup happens before overload resolution.

I believe the relevant section is [[basic.lookup]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#1), specifically

> […] The declarations found by name lookup shall either all denote the same entity or shall all denote functions or function templates; in the latter case, the declarations are said to form a set of overloaded functions ([over.load]). […]

In your case, the name `sort` denotes both, the object `boot::sort` as well as the set of overloaded functions `std::sort`. Therefore, name lookup fails.

Your code is really no different from if you had written, for example

```
namespace baz {
    int a;
}

namespace boot {
    int a;
}

void foo() {
    using namespace baz;
    using namespace boot;
    a = 42;  // error: reference to 'a' is ambiguous
}
```

[Try it out here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'namespace+baz+%7B%0A++++int+a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Anamespace+boot+%7B%0A++++int+a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++using+namespace+baz%3B%0A++++using+namespace+boot%3B%0A++++a+%3D+42%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:44.627450980392155,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g81,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:26.04918890633177,l:'4',m:50.63091482649842,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.1',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:49.36908517350158,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:55.372549019607845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4); compare this to [a case that actually has an ambiguous function call](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'namespace+baz+%7B%0A++++void+f()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Anamespace+boot+%7B%0A++++void+f()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++using+namespace+baz%3B%0A++++using+namespace+boot%3B%0A++++f()%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:44.627450980392155,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g81,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:26.04918890633177,l:'4',m:50.63091482649842,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.1',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:49.36908517350158,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:55.372549019607845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4); note how the error message is the same as in your case, specifically referring to the name itself being ambiguous rather than the function call.

Comment: I think this is actually the right answer. And I would like to add that if both the template function `sort` and the lambda `sort` were declared in the same namespace, it would be an error. You cannot have a function and non-function with the same name in the same namespace. So there could never be an overload set that has both true functions and function-like objects.

Comment: Seems like a right answet to me. If there is something that can be done to workaround my problem I would be thankful for comment/answer edit.

Comment: @Scheff indeed, I must've mixed up the URLs somehow. Should be fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @bartop can you not just remove the using directives and/or use fully-qualified names, e.g., `baz::sort`!?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Sure can, and I do it currently. Even though I still wonder if there is different way to avoid this ambiguity

Comment: @bartop I don't think there possibly could be a way to avoid this. As the passage quoted above says: You must never have a situation where the same name refers to more than one entity unless it's the name of an overload set. The only way to avoid the ambiguity is to not make the name ambiguous. In your case, that would mean either renaming one of the two things or not introducing the name of both things into the same scope.